# url rewrite intelligencia Conditions

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config

I have using URL Rewriter Intelligencia,

I have teh following conditions:

```
<rewrite url="~/music-bands" to="~/TheBand.aspx"/>
<rewrite url="~/gigs" to="~/gigs.aspx"/>
<rewrite url="~/music-cds-australia" to="~/CDS.aspx"/>
<rewrite url="~/new-music-videos" to="~/NewVideos.aspx"/>
<rewrite url="~/musicians-photo-gallery" to="~/Photo Gallery.aspx"/>
<rewrite url="~/blog" to="~/Blog.aspx"/>
```

However it seems to be writing everything with "blog" in it" so blog.css wont work.
neither will _images/blog/blogs.png etc

Any idea how i can only make it rewrite www.mywebpage.com/blog  and nothign else?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the last rule with: `<rewrite url="~/blog$" to="~/Blog.aspx" />`

The dollar sign ($) when parsed as a .NET `RegularExpresion` denotes the end of the string; this will prevent `/blog.css` from hitting the rule above

Comment: ~/blog[/]*$ (note the square brackets and forward slash) will also catch a trailing forward slash ~/blog/